# enable any java code coverage tool in jar file to generate output

Tags: java, jar, code-coverage, executable-jar

Is there any tool which can be embedded in jar file and generate code coverage in output file each time jar is run.

plz dont mention any eclipse/netbeans plugin, i cant use IDE.

Comment: Try Googling for "java command line coverage tool".  It worked for me.

Comment: i did it and it gave me a lot of options as plugins for IDE but not without any IDE, why this -ve vote?

Comment: Did you use the search terms I suggested???  I did, and I saw Emma and some other command line Java coverage tools in the first page of search results.  Like I said, Google worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use emma.jar of Emma code coverage tool. But it will not generate the report by its own you have to execute some commands for it. But its very good and generate report in various formats like xml or html

Comment: let me see how to use it